# Traversal String Representation

Tags: string, binary-tree, traversal, tree-traversal, inorder

I am working on a in-order traversal and I am having difficulty creating a recursive in-order tree traversal in which a string is being made to look like this [ 1, 2, 3 ]. Instead I get something like this [ 1, 2, 3, ]. I am not sure how to get rid of that extra comma after the 3.

```
def inorder(self):
    if self.__root == None:
        return '[ ]'
    else:
        return '[ ' + self.__inorder(self.__root) + ']'

def __inorder(self, root):
    rep = ''
    if root != None:
        rep = self.__inorder(root.leftC) + str(root.value)  + ', ' +  self.__inorder(root.rightC)
    return rep
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Slicing

```
>>> a = "[1,2,3,]"
>>> a[0:len(a)-2]+a[len(a)-1]
'[1,2,3]'
```

Comment: this isn't a list though it is a string

Comment: My example is also for String. Slicing works same way for String since String is a tuple of chars

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean or how I would incorporate that into my code?

Comment: return rep[0:len(rep)-1] in __inorder method

Comment: this doesn't work. If I do return rep[0:len(rep)-1] then I get [ 1,2, 3]

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: not I need [ 1, 2, 3 ]. I got [ 1,2, 3 ] notice that there is no spacing between the 1 and 2 with in the second one.